# Do I Need / How do I Set Up Server In My React/Redux/Firestore App?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, server, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a react/redux/firestore app and I understand that react is a frontend library and firestore is a backend nosql database, but how do you add a "server" into the mix of this?

For instance if I wanted to make a query on a bunch of my firestore data to find the average price of an item across tons of records and then use this information to run computational heavy optimizations how would I want to do that in my app? Should I use a server? And if so what and how? Should I just use cloud functions?

Because in theory I could just make a react/redux/firestore app where all of the computation is done in functions in my react frontend with data pulled from firestore but I assume that is not the best way to do things? What should I be doing instead?

**TLDR** Do I need to offload some computation to a server or cloud functions or something in a react/firestore app? How are things like this usually done or do people just get data from Firestore and then do all of their logic in react? My assumption would be react is just for setting up the ui and button/display functionality, firestore is for storing my data, and something else is where I would do things like find averages based on my firestore data and run optimizations to then pass the answers back to my react frontend to display?

Comment: TLDR: Yes you need a server and a backend application written by a language to speak with Firebase. This depends on your knowledge. The language can be NodeJS, Pyhton, PHP etc. React is interested in just the data coming to it, nothing more. The data can come in many ways from many different applications written by any language.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, would it be smart to do something like this with google cloud functions since I am already using firestore? Like make a request in react to a cloud function that spins up a server and returns my answer? I don't have experience with cloud functions but I assume I could do something like this?

Comment: I'm not experienced with cloud functions but probably you can do this with cloud functions without a server. This is similar to Amazon Lambda functions I think which I don't have any experience also. Serverless fashion :) But, you need to write some backend code again, this does not change. As a learner, if you are new to React and want to learn the frontend first, just stay away from backend a little bit. I started with React -> Redux -> Backend (NodeJS, Express). Nowadays, I want to check serverless architecture and cloud or lambda functions. But hey, it is your decision.

Comment: I would suggest using firebase cloud functions for this.

Comment: @FrankTheTank, I've found out how wrong I am and how I mislead you now! Duh! You don't need to have a backend to play with Firebase. [See for an example app](https://css-tricks.com/intro-firebase-react/). Sorry for the misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to try to stay in the firebase ecosystem you could hook Cloud Functions to respond to Firebase events, like `onWrite()`, `onCreate()`, etc. Run your heavy computations in there and save that data into the db.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events?hl=es-419